# Is it possible to run multiple SQL statements in parallel within the same transaction from .net?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, t-sql

I want to upsert to 7 tables in SQL Server. I first SqlBulkCopy into 7 staging tables and then I merge them to the real tables. I need it to be faster, so I'm wondering if there is a way to run these in parallel but within the same transaction, because if anything fails I want to roll back all of it.

Thanks

Comment: Possibly, because SQL Server supports nested transactions.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an ssis package and get this etl in a container using the TransactionOption on the container you can have it roll back if it fails. I think this is the fastest way... Other wise you can check if the transactions finished using a table ... But that's silly